# Bash Script printf colors from variable?

Tags: c, bash, shell

I was hoping to see if someone can point out what I am doing wrong because I am stumped. I am trying to learn bash scripting to deploy a dev test server. One of the things I am trying to achieve is outputting status outputs when a part of the script completes or an action completes. As an example:

```
    printf "[ %s ] %s distribution detected. Validated as supported by this script.\n" "$PASSED" "$LINUX_DISTRO"
```

The problem I am having is formatting the value of the first string, `%s`, which is `$PASSED`. In the beginning of the script I have defined `$PASSED` as

```
PASSED="\e[32mPASSED\e[0m"
```

However, when I go to execute the script, the output looks like the following:

```
[ \e[32mPASSED\e[0m ] CENTOS distribution detected. Validated as supported by this script.
```

Instead of the correct output which looks like:

```
[ PASSED ] CENTOS distribution detected. Validated as supported by this script.
```

Where "PASSED" is written in green coloring.

However, I did notice that if I do the following:

```
printf "[ $PASSED ] %s distribution detected. Validated as supported by this script.\n" "$LINUX_DISTRO"
```

The above behaves correctly, but I believe isn't the correct way of doing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't hard-code terminal escapes in strings, until you know what terminal type you are writing to.  Not all the world is a VT100!  I suggest you use `tput` or similar - that's what it's for.

Comment: @TobySpeight I will take a look at `tput`. Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want bash to interpret the backslash characters. Use `%b` instead of `%s` in your printf. So instead you should have the following.

```
printf "[ %b ] %s distribution detected. Validated as supported by this script.\n" $PASSED $LINUX_DISTRO
```

Also, I modified your variable.

```
PASSED="\e[00;32mPASSED\e[0m"
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `%b`, this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another (non-standard) solution is to put the escape character directly in the original string, rather than `\e` for `printf` to interpret.

```
PASSED=$'\e[32mPASSED\e[0m'
printf '[ %s ] some test\n' "$PASSED"
```

However, this assumes that your script is run by `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh` (which might *be* `bash`, but run in POSIX-compliant mode).

Using `%b` has the same problem: it is specific to `bash`, and you may not want to assume that `bash` is the shell executing your script.

A fully POSIX-compliant solution is to use `printf` itself to create the value of `PASSED`.

```
# \e not supported by POSIX; use \033 (octal) instead.
PASSED=$(printf '\033[32mPASSED\033[0m')
printf '[ %s ] some test\n' "$PASSED"
```